# Css3 media query not loading

Tags: css, media-queries

I have this media query add to my main css file. when I attempt to load the page on my ipad I'm not getting the styled media query below. any reason why this may be happening?

```
/* iPad [portrait + landscape] */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
    #main_rgt {
        width: 440px;
        height: 495px;
        float: left;
        overflow: visible;
    }
    .chkbox3 .chkpos {
        float: right;
        margin-right: 10px;    
    }
}
```

Comment: have u the same styles set for other devices/screens?

Comment: Please check your override media query css come after you original style.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks That's wrong, retina iPad returns the same screen size, only the density change. Media queries are handled the same.

Answer (score 2):

Try to put this in the head of your page.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: All my media queries were ignored completely, until I added this meta tag, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want this @media query to override some other CSS rules (not applicable for iPad) it should be placed after these rules, or make them more specific.

Comment: I've tested the media query with a simple background change and it works. I think you're right.

Answer (score 1):

i used bootstrap in a press site but it does not worked on IE8, i used css3-mediaqueries.js javascript but still not working. if you want your media query to work with this javascript file add screen to your media query line in css

here is an example :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />


<style>
     @media screen and (max-width:900px) {}
     @media screen and (min-width:900px) and (max-width:1200px) {}
     @media screen and (min-width:1200px) {}
</style>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
```

css Link line as simple as above line.
this works as strong as i believe in god :D.

Answer (score 0):

use this, it should helps

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    enter style here
}
```